# Bunch of girls/Buncha girls

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, differences, idioms

as English isn't my first language, I don't really 'feel' whether bunch of girls/buncha girls is offensive, friendly, etc.? Could you tell me what's the proper meaning of the phrase? I hear it in movies, in different contexts, and it often seems negative, but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The term *bunch of* is not inherently offensive at all. It is synonymous with describing *a group of X* or *a lot of X*. It can refer to anything from inanimate objects to people. For example, one can eat a bunch of grapes, or read a bunch of books, or meet a bunch of people.

Comment: What about: you're acting like a bunch of girls?

Comment: This depends on the context. Replace it with "you're acting like a group of girls;" is that offensive?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it would just mean a group of girls. *Bunch* wouldn't be the most common collective noun to use, but it wouldn't have much of a strong nuance either way.

Used of a group of men, it would be an insult, suggesting that they are inferior men (and hence insulting all women by extension, as well as the targeted men).